# Right way to add different configurations for different build types and product flavours

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

In my application I have 4 environments i.e **Dev**, **SIT**, **UAT**, **Release**. For each environment I have a build type with it's own configuration. Much like the suggested way, e.g:

```
buildTypes {
    Dev {
        buildConfigField "String", 'BASE_URL', "https://dev-api.yourbackend.com"
    }
    SIT {
        buildConfigField "String", 'BASE_URL', "https://sit-api.yourbackend.com"
    }
    UAT {
        buildConfigField "String", 'BASE_URL', "https://uat-api.yourbackend.com"
    }
    Release {
        buildConfigField "String", 'BASE_URL', "https://api.yourbackend.com"
    }
}
```

But now I have 5-6 different such configurations, not just the `BASE_URL`. Like `ClientId`, `ClientSecret` etc..

Plus I have 2 product flavours, meaning I need to create 8 different build variants and have all these 5-6 configurations inside each such variant. All that looks clumsy.

1 other solution I found is to create a folder for each of the build variant like `flavour1Dev`, `flavour2Sit`, `flavour2Uat` etc.. and have the config file specific to that variant inside that folder. This again involves 8 different folders and keeps growing as we add more environments.

Is there a better way of handling this, probably like a `config.gradle` file where I can only have these configurations and import it back in the `app/build.gradle`, a way of modularising the whole build variant configurations.

**Update-1**

I tried this as per @Md. Asaduzzaman's Answer:

**build.gradle**

```
…
…
apply from: './config.gradle'


…
…
android {
    …
    …
    defaultConfig {
        …
        …
        buildConfigField('String', ‘BASE_URL’, '"https://default.yourbackend.com”')
    }
    …
    …
}
```

**config.gradle**

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        dev {
            buildConfigField('String', ‘BASE_URL’, '"https://dev.yourbackend.com”')
        }
        sit {
            buildConfigField('String', ‘BASE_URL’, '"https://sit.yourbackend.com”')
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is that in the generated `BuildConfig`, I still see the default values:

```
public static final String BASE_URL = "https://default.yourbackend.com";
```

Answer (score 0):

You already mentioned the solution yourself by creating separate `config.gradle` file. I try to implement it like below:

**Step - 1:** Create `config.gradle` inside your `app` folder and add all the configurations.

```
android {

    buildTypes {

        Dev {
            buildConfigField "String", 'BASE_URL', "https://dev-api.yourbackend.com"
        }

        SIT {
            buildConfigField "String", 'BASE_URL', "https://sit-api.yourbackend.com"
        }

        UAT {
            buildConfigField "String", 'BASE_URL', "https://uat-api.yourbackend.com"
        }

        Release {
            buildConfigField "String", 'BASE_URL', "https://api.yourbackend.com"
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        flavor1 {
            /*implementation*/
        }

        flavor2 {
            /*implementation*/
        }

        flavor3 {
            /*implementation*/
        }
    }
}
```

**Step -2:** Include the `config.gradle` in your `app/build.gradle`.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: './config.gradle'

....
```

Comment: @Housefly, Check my answer

Comment: I update my question with the changes as per your answer. Please check that.

Comment: Have you checked by changing variants by side menu? It's working in my case

Comment: Besides this you should also build your project. I have found some issue in your code when try to copy-paste and build. Please check

Comment: @Housefly, Isn't it help you?